# Make all rows the same height MUI grid

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui, css-grid

```js
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Card>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia
              width={1}
              alt="Meal Products POS"
              sx={{ maxWidth: 400 }}
              component="img"
              image={themesObj.pos.featuredProduct}
            />

            <CardContent sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                Meal Products POS
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Card>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia
              width={1}
              alt="Barcode normal products POS"
              sx={{ maxWidth: 400 }}
              component="img"
              image={themesObj.pos.normalProduct}
            />
            <CardContent sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                Barcode normal products POS
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Card>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardContent sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              <NotInterestedIcon sx={{ fontSize: 200 }} />
              <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                Return a product
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I have this grid component, and it displays the following:

[image]

It is depending on the image height, it makes the card height.

I want to make the height the same for all the cards, dynamically. but how?

I am using the newest version of MUI as of now (v5.10.3).

what to do?

Comment: @TrollBearPig, no. I changed the design to another idea. I wish I found the solution though